# @angular-devkit/architect has no exported member ArchitectHost

Tags: angular

I want to write my own angular devkit architect builder to extend the angular cli with the functionality to stamp out a version-info.ts file for angular projects, that they can show version information in angular components.

Now I want to test it, but the official instructions are not in sync with the package reality.

[Angular.io Testing a builder](https://angular.io/guide/cli-builder#testing-a-builder)

The instruction manual says

```
import { Architect, ArchitectHost } from '@angular-devkit/architect';
```

but IntelliJ Idea complains about

```
@angular-devkit/architect does not have an exported member 'ArchitectHost'
```

Does someone know how to do testing of angular devkit architect builders correctly?

Answer (score 0):

I think, the answer lies in the [example link](https://github.com/mgechev/cli-builders-demo) below the heading
[**Testing a builder**](https://angular.io/guide/cli-builder#testing-a-builder)

The `ArchitectHost` Class seems to be deprecated in favor of

```
import { TestingArchitectHost } from '@angular-devkit/architect/testing';
```